# Skip cells while filling values

Tags: vba, skip

I am trying to fill cells from D3 to AH30 with "1".And I have dates in D1 to AH1 cells . But I do not need to fill the cells with "1" if corresponding cell in first row has a weekend date in it.

I tried below code. But its filling "1" in all cells including weekend days

```
    Function CheckWeekday_and_fill()
    Dim dDate As Date
     dDate = Range("D1").Value       
    For row = 3 To 30 ' rows for cells with date in it
    For col = 4 To 34 ' cols for cells with date in it

    Select Case Weekday(dDate)
    Case vbSaturday, vbSunday
    Cells(row, col).Value = " "
    Case Else
    Cells(row, col).Value = "1"
    End Select
    dDate = dDate + 1
    Next col
    Next row                    
    End Function
```

Comment: Is this VBA? Tag the programming language to get better help.

Comment: Yes, VBA. Updated Tag. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Function CheckWeekday_and_fill()

Dim dDate As Date      
For row = 3 To 30 ' rows for cells with date in it
For col = 4 To 34 ' cols for cells with date in it
    dDate = Cells(1, col).Value
    Select Case Weekday(dDate)
    Case vbSaturday, vbSunday
    Cells(row, col).Value = " "
    Case Else
    Cells(row, col).Value = "1"
    End Select
Next col
Next row                    

End Function
```

Comment: I am afraid that I got Type mismatch error at dDate = Range("D" & col).Value.Also my Dates are in D1 through AH1. D4 is where  I want to fill with 1 based on weekday/weekend in D1